# how to place previously selected value at UIPickerview bar

Tags: iphone

I am displaying my array objects in a pickerview.

My array contains {one,two,three,four,five}

When I select a value in picker view, I am getting that value using
`- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {`

If I select two, exit from the picker view and for next time it display one in picker view bar.

But I need to display previously selected value.

I think this is understandable otherwise let me add comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
[pickerView selectRow:selectedItem inComponent:0 animated:YES]; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to store the value of the selected row in a variable call it `selectedRow` and when the view appears use this method on the object of pickerView

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
selectedRow = row;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear
{
  [picker  selectRow:selectedRow inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}
```

to select the row in the particular component.

Answer (score 0):

call method

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated
```

After displaying it for second time

Answer (score 0):

In case the pickerview was `alloc/inited` and then added as a subview at the view then

```
[picker selectRow:selectedRow inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

works only after

```
[self.view addSubview:picker];
```